# Error Message: redirect_uri is not owned by the application

Tags: iframe, facebook, facebook-php-sdk

::UPDATE:: LINKS DO NOT EXIST ANYMORE!

Very strange indeed, this is definitely a bug! I did a test with app_id from another application and it worked.
See for yourself:

https://apps.megalopes.com/megabraziltv/test.php (app_id correct)

https://apps.megalopes.com/megabraziltv/test2.php (app_id from another application)

---/---

I found several people with the same question and all the answers are equal:
Site URL is not same as REQUEST_URI (Redirecting URL)

My app setting are:

Secure Page Tab URL: apps.megalopes.com/megabraziltv/...

App Domain: megalopes.com

code:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
      <script src="http://connect.facebook.net/pt_BR/all.js">
      </script>
      <script>
         FB.init({ 
            appId:'123456789', cookie:true, 
            status:true, xfbml:true 
         });

         FB.ui({ method: 'apprequests', 
            message: 'Here is a new Requests dialog...'});
      </script>
```

This simple code is not redirecting to any other url. I tested on the js console getting the same results. Sometimes works and sometimes I get this error message:

> API Error Code: 191  API Error Description: The specified URL is not
>   owned by the application  Error Message: redirect_uri is not owned by
>   the application.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Regardless of being page tab or canvas, you must identify the website Site URL in https://developers.facebook.com/apps

How I fixed:

App Domain: megalopes.com (domain)

Site URL: / Secure Canvas URL: / Secure Page Tab URL: https://www.megalopes.com (subdomain)

Answer (score 1):

I think I have run into something similar before.

In the summary page of your app ensure both the Secure Canvas URL and Page Tab URL are populated.

Answer (score 1):

The URL in my **redirect_uri** should have "http://" in the beginning. It was missing the protocol information, thus leading Facebook not to recognize my website and throw this annoying 191 error. I finally found out after one hour pulling the hair I (still) have left.

Comment: Thank you. Much hair was pulled over here. I'm pretty sure the LINK parameter should also include http(s)://

Answer (score 0):

It's because of domain URL that you mentioned in facebook's mistake. Domain URL wont be like www.site.com
Update your domain url like subdomain.site.com.
Now it surely work.

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a *channel* page, which allows "cross domain communication in certain browsers"

This is an html page (saying */channel.html*) on your server, which only contains :

```
<script src="//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>
```

And make the Javascript SDK aware of it :

```
FB.init({
    appId: 'xxxxxx',
    cookie: true, 
    channelUrl: location.protocol + '//' + location.host + '/channel.html'
});
```

More about this :

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.init/
- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/