# API Error Code: 191 on Facebook application

Tags: facebook

I received the error message: "http://www.facebook.com/4oh4.php" while browsing my app, http://apps.facebook.com/get-eye-rating.

All settings are correct; I have created thousands of apps with the same settings before.

When I try to browse directly through http://www.rat32.com/fruitname-a/ it gives following error:

> Error
> An error occurred with Get your eyes ratings. Please try again later.
>
> API Error Code: 191
> API Error Description: The specified URL is not owned by the application
> Error Message: redirect_uri is not owned by the application.

Previously I've never received such error messages.

Comment: Perhaps this link will help: http://stackoverflow.com/q/5835014/1329524

Comment: What about this one: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8393646/1329524

Comment: i deleted previous app and created new one with new folder name. It worked now smoothly. I don't know whats happening with facebook. Facebook really sucks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have deleted previous app and created the new app with the same settings. It was perhaps the facebook internal system error.